# How to use LuaTeX `append_to_vlist_filter` callback

Tags: luatex, callback

I am considering a solution to the automatic grid typesetting problem though LuaTeX callbacks. The most relevant one seems to be `append_to_vlist_filter`. (`vpack` can also work, I support, but a less elegant solution)

However, it seems that it does work properly. The documents is quite vague on its return value.

```
function(<node> box, <string> locationcode, <number prevdepth>, <boolean> mirrored) 
    return list, prevdepth
end
```

> It is ok to return nothing in which case you also need to flush the
>   box or deal with it yourself. The prevdepth is also optional.
>   Locations are box, alignment, equation, equation_number and
>   post_linebreak

Below is a minimal example,

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{
  function apvlist(head)
    return head
  end
  luatexbase.add_to_callback("append_to_vlist_filter", apvlist, "apvlist")
}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

I assumed that the return value `list` means the head of a node list. In the simple example, the original box is returned as the head of a single node list. Yet, when compiled there's no page output.

What does the document mean by *flush the box or deal with it yourself*?

Comment: ltj-direction.lua from the luatexja package has an example of the use of this callback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd found the same example as Ulrike in luatexja, and so I think the identity function is something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{
  function apvlist(head,c,p,b)
    print('adding ' .. type(head) .. ' in context ' .. c)
    node.write(head)
    return nil
  end
  luatexbase.add_to_callback("append_to_vlist_filter", apvlist, "apvlist")
}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

which typesets Test and echoes

```
adding userdata in context post_linebreak
adding userdata in context box
adding userdata in context box
adding userdata in context box
adding userdata in context box
adding userdata in context box
```

But the details are still a bit vague.

Comment: I tried this on a longer example (the MWE at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381032/make-a-variable-length-horizontal-rule-depending-on-the-text-width-of-the-title)), and unfortunately this doesn't appear to be the identity function exactly. Still a mystery…

Answer (score 1):

The example in question should now work correctly after a LuaTeX fix dated 2020/3/9.

The behavior of `append_to_vlist_filter` is explained in the [source code](https://gitlab.lisn.upsaclay.fr/texlive/luatex/-/blob/1.17.0/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/tex/packaging.c#L1550-L1582). The callback is responsible for creating interline skips, which is conveniently handled by the `node.prepend_prevdepth` function. So, the identity callback is like:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{
  function apvlist(head, loc, prev_dp, mirror)
    local new_head, new_dp = node.prepend_prevdepth(head, prev_dp)
    % new_head is either head unchanged, or a skip linked with head
    return new_head, new_dp
    % alternatively, you can flush them manually and return nil
  end
  luatexbase.add_to_callback("append_to_vlist_filter", apvlist, "apvlist")
}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{20pt}

Test 1

Test 2
\end{document}
```

Another interesting usage is https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/581716.