# Create a section rule that is the same width as the section title

Tags: titlesec, rules

I would like to create something that looks like this:[image: desired look]

Now, I have seen [a solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381032/make-a-variable-length-horizontal-rule-depending-on-the-text-width-of-the-title) that works with the asker's *example* environment (using `\predisplaysize`). However, my desired solution is a little different. In particular, I am trying to use `\titleformat`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor, lipsum}
\usepackage[calcwidth]{titlesec}

\definecolor{carmine}{rgb}{0.68, 0.0, 0.09}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
{\color{carmine}\S$\,$\thesection}{0.5em}{\color{black}}
%This creates a rule that matches the full page's width, rather than the title's
[\vspace{-1.5em}\rule{\textwidth}{0.2pt}] 

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-1]
\end{document}
```

This looks like:

[image: current attempt]

So far, my attempts to use the `titlesec` have been unsuccessful. When using `\titlewidth` as an argument to `\rule`, I find that the underline completely disappears. As well, the example given in the [documentation](http://muug.ca/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) draws a rule (of full page width) *above* the section name.

Is there a way to create a rule under a section title that has the same width as the title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not very good style, but here we go…

The documentation mentions there can be wrong measurements of  titles with the `hang` option (which b.t.w. is the default). You can use the `block` style, which is the same as hang as long as you don't have multiline titles.

Also, I suggest using the `[T1]` font encoding, as this will load `cmsuper` which has a `bold` version of `§`, and I don't think yopu want to raise the rule by 1.5em: this would make it strike through the title.  `1.5ex` is more sensible.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor, lipsum}
\usepackage[calcwidth]{titlesec}

\definecolor{carmine}{rgb}{0.68, 0.0, 0.09}

\titleformat{\section}[block] {\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
{\color{carmine}\S\,\thesection}{0.5em}{\color{black}}
%This creates a rule that matches the full page's width, rather than the title's
 [\vspace{-1.5ex}\rule{\titlewidth}{0.2pt}]

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction.}

\lipsum[1-1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note:*
If you do have multiline section titles, there exists a workaround to make titles hang with the `block` style.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. Thank you for your answer and your feedback, @Bernard!